# does eclipse have it own library?

Tags: java, eclipse

Does eclipse have its own library, or does java have a big shared library that all IDE's use?

Thanks, and sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Eclipse has more than a library -- it has its own platform.

Comment: Can you please explain "has its own platform"?

Comment: Please have a look yourself: [The Eclipse Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/platform/)

Comment: read it briefly. Still don't know whether or not it has a class library.

Comment: I got my answer :) thanks hovercraft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has [its own platform/framework](http://www.eclipse.org/platform/) for developing GUI applications in general and IDE in particular. This in turn is based on the OSGi standard for modular Java applications.

Eclipse even includes a native code widget library (SWT) that is used instead of Swing.

Large parts of this infrastructure are shared among the Eclipse family of IDE (such as Aptana), but not really with other IDE such as Netbeans. OTOH, some task-specific code, such as drivers to connect to source control systems and databases, is usable with other platforms as well.

Eclipse also has its own Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

All IDEs don't use a big shared library.

IntelliJ is nothing like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php) is the Java infrastructure of Eclipse. It is used by Eclipse and is popular outside of it as well, but there is no "library that all IDE's share".